# Find range of $m$ such that $|x^2-3x+2 | = mx$ has 4 distinct solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, absolute-value

> $|x^2-3x+2 | = mx$

I think that $(x^2-3x+2) = mx$ or $-(x^2-3x+2) = mx$

For $-(x^2-3x+2) = mx$, $D > 0$,
$m = 3 \pm \sqrt{8}$

For $(x^2-3x+2) = mx$, $D > 0$,
$m = -3 \pm \sqrt{8}$

Now. What do you think it's the range?
Note that $ |x^2-3x+2 | = mx$ which means $mx > 0$ isn't it?

Comment: Try splitting the equation $|a|=b$ into \begin{cases}a=b\\-a=b\end{cases} and solve for the discriminant in each case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving $|x^2-3x+2|=mx$ is same as finding the intersection of the graph of $y=|x^2-3x+2|$ and the lines $y=mx$ passing through the origin. Here is a figure to better illustrate the idea.
[image]

By changing the value of $m$ we are changing the slope of the line passing through the origin. ***Unless this line is tangent or  passes through the middle cusp in the graph there cannot be $4$ solutions.*** This means the first instance the line will intersect the graph at $4$ points (tangent point is counted as double point) is when this line is tangent to the graph.

**Ques: what is the point of tangency?**

Let $(h,k)$ be the point on (the middle cusp) the curve such that the line $y=mx$ is tangent. Then using the fact that slope of the line $\frac{k}{h}$ should be the same as the slope of the curve (in particular the middle cusp which is given by $y=-x^2+3x-2$), we get
$$m=\frac{k}{h}=\frac{dy}{dx}\Big|_{(h,k)}=-2h+3.$$
But $k=-h^2+3h-2$, so this gives $h=\pm \sqrt{2}$. Note that the negative value is not possible. So $\color{red}{h=\sqrt{2}}$.

Observe that the slope $m=-2h+3=3-2\sqrt{2}$.

Since you have asked for $4$ **distinct** solutions, so 
$$\color{red}{0 <m < 3-2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I think it is right. But the key answer is 0<m<0.172. Or 0<x<3-$\sqrt8$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter I have edited the solution that has the corrected version. I had mistakenly thought the point of tangency is the middle point of the cusp.

Comment: Point of tangency = h, k =  $\sqrt2$, $3\sqrt2 - 4$ . Or do you mean the use of tangency? Because any line above tangency lines will intersect graph 2 times only

Comment: Why is the tangent point counted as doubled  when it only has $ h, k$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter for tangency even though physically there is only one point but it is referred as double because the idea is that the tangent is intersecting at two *equal* points. Think of  a secant drawn on a circle and when the two points approach towards each other, the secant tends to becoming a tangent.

Comment: I forgot how to solve it. For D>0 so  (-3-m)^2 > 8 and (-3+m)^2 > 8. And for m = -0,1. It is still makes D>0. Why?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$x^2-3x+2=\pm mx$$ has two distinct real solutions when the discriminant is strictly positive, i.e.

$$(\pm m-3)^2-8=(\pm m-3-\sqrt8)(\pm m-3+\sqrt8)>0.$$

The condition must hold for the two signs, and the general condition is

$$((m-3-\sqrt8>0\land m-3+\sqrt8>0)\lor(m-3-\sqrt8<0\land m-3+\sqrt8<0))\land\\
((-m-3-\sqrt8>0\land-m-3+\sqrt8>0)\lor(-m-3-\sqrt8<0\land-m-3+\sqrt8<0)).$$

This simplifies to

$$(m-3-\sqrt8>0\lor m-3+\sqrt8<0)\land\\
(-m-3-\sqrt8>0\lor-m-3+\sqrt8<0).$$

The rest is yours.

---

The graphical approach (as by Anurag) is interesting. We can consider the equation

$$\left|x-3+\frac2x\right|=m$$ and plot the LHS. From the plot, we see that the solution will consist of two intervals, $(0,a)$ and $(b,\infty)$, where $a,b$ are extremal values of the LHS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explain it. But i kinda confused with conditional statements

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: draw the intervals on a real line.

Comment: Oh. Yes. The rest. Will be : $-3+\sqrt8 < m < 3-\sqrt8$ or $m>3+\sqrt8$ or $ m<-3-\sqrt8$ ? y always positive. So. m is positive. How to proceed after this?

Comment: Since the condition statements you stated based on D>0 which is 2 distinct solutions. How the conditional statements for 4 distinct solutions...

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: "The condition must hold for the two signs"

Comment: Oh. Yes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = x^2-(3+m)x+2$, the discriminant is

$D = (3+m)^2-4\cdot 2 = (m+3)^2-8.$

This gives you a quadratic polynomial in $m$. If you have two solutions for $m$, you get in total four solutions of $f(x)$.